# Flow equivalent to Java Wildcard?

Tags: flowtype

Is there an equivalent to [Java's Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) in Flow?

Here's my example code I've been working on as a test:

```
type InterfaceType = {
    var1 : number,
};

type ActualType = InterfaceType & {
    var2 : string,
};

type InterfaceGenericType<T : InterfaceType> = {
    var3 : T,
}

type ActualGenericType = InterfaceGenericType<ActualType> & {

}


class State<T : InterfaceGenericType<InterfaceType>> {

    prop : T;

    constructor(arg : T) : State<T> {
        this.prop = arg;
        return this;
    }
}


let actual : ActualType = {
    var1: 1,
    var2: "two",
};

let actualGeneric : ActualGenericType = {
    var3 : actual,
}

let s2 = new State(actualGeneric);
```

This is the flow error I'm getting:

```
    40: let s2 = new State(actualGeneric);
                           ^ Cannot call `State` with `actualGeneric` bound to `arg` because property `var2` is missing in `InterfaceType` [1] but exists in object type [2] in property `var3`.
        References:
        20: class State<T : InterfaceGenericType<InterfaceType>> {
                                                 ^ [1]
        7: type ActualType = InterfaceType & {
                                             ^ [2]
```

I know I can get around the issue by doing:
`class State<I : InterfaceType, T : InterfaceGenericType<I>> {`
but I'm trying to not have to declare both types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can trim down your code a bit to remove the class:

```
type InterfaceType = { var1: number };
type ActualType = InterfaceType & { var2: string, };

type InterfaceGenericType<T : InterfaceType> = {
    var3: T,
};

let actual: ActualType = {
    var1: 1,
    var2: "two",
};

let actualGeneric: InterfaceGenericType<ActualType> = {
    var3: actual,
};

let v: InterfaceGenericType<InterfaceType> = actualGeneric;
```

I can't speak to Java since I don't know it, but I can tell you how to fix this. If we look at the error for this code:

```
17: let v: InterfaceGenericType<InterfaceType> = actualGeneric;
                                                 ^ Cannot assign `actualGeneric` to `v` because property `var2` is missing in `InterfaceType` [1] but exists in object type [2] in type argument `T` [3].
    References:
    17: let v: InterfaceGenericType<InterfaceType> = actualGeneric;
                                    ^ [1]
    2: type ActualType = InterfaceType & { var2: string, };
                                         ^ [2]
    4: type InterfaceGenericType<T : InterfaceType> = {
                                 ^ [3]
```

The core issue is that `v`'s type `InterfaceGenericType<InterfaceType>` would for example allow you to do

```
v.var3 = { var1: 42 };
```

because that is a valid `InterfaceType` object. That *isn't* a valid `ActualType` object, but by assigning `actualGeneric` to `v`, you've essentially erased that type information, which means that if your code were allowed as-is, the assignment would corrupt your `actualGeneric` object's type.

The fix for this is to tell Flow that the `var3` property is read-only, by changing

```
var3: T,
```

to be

```
+var3: T,
```